# Android Studio how to make relative layouts circle around a relative layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I want all of my relative layouts to be around one relative layout in a circle shape.

Here is what I have 
[My Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO9gF.jpg)

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Here is my XML code and I don't have any constraints because they don't seem to help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.alexei.roses.ImageDescription"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/s1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/geo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/circulargeo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Geographic Origin"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="234dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="119dp" />

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/circulargeo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/geographic"
        app:civ_border_color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:civ_border_width="4dp"

        app:civ_shadow="true"
        app:civ_shadow_color="@android:color/black"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="248dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/s2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="7dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="181dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sci"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/circularsci"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Scientific Name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/circularsci"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/scientificname"
        app:civ_border_color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"

        app:civ_border_width="4dp"
        app:civ_shadow="true"
        app:civ_shadow_color="@android:color/black"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="28dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="327dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/s3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="326dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/circularcha"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Characteristics"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="234dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="119dp" />

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/circularcha"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/characteristics"
        app:civ_border_color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:civ_border_width="4dp"

        app:civ_shadow="true"
        app:civ_shadow_color="@android:color/black"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="248dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/s4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="181dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="278dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cul"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/circularcul"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Cultivation"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-243dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="53dp" />

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/circularcul"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cultivation"
        app:civ_border_color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:civ_border_width="4dp"

        app:civ_shadow="true"
        app:civ_shadow_color="@android:color/black"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="248dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/s5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="253dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/circulardis"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Diseases and Pests"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-243dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="53dp" />

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/circulardis"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/diseases"
        app:civ_border_color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:civ_border_width="4dp"

        app:civ_shadow="true"
        app:civ_shadow_color="@android:color/black"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="248dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="142dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flowername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flowerimage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="150dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="290dp" />

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/flowerimage"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:civ_border_width="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/amaryllis"
        app:civ_shadow="true"
        app:civ_shadow_color="@android:color/black"
        app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="117dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="135dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe you can try ConstraintLayout ?

Answer (score 0):

if I get exactly want you want, if you want the ralative layout to be rounded , I encourage you to wrap the relative layout in cardView , after which you will set the cardCornerRadius

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
            card_view:contentPadding="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
            card_view:cardMaxElevation="6dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#0077ff"
            >

              <RelativeLayout>
                ...
              </RelativeLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

You can play with the attributes to get extractly what you want

Comment: I don't want a relative layout to be rounded. I want to have a circle menu. Where all the small images are around the big image equally distributed.